# How do I increment a value conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying 3 buttons and if I click the start and stop button within 1 second, then it is not showing any effects but if I do that multiple number of times then that should result in the increment which it is not.

I want it to show the milliseconds that have passed between the simultaneous start stop buttons also.

```
var secs = 0;
var mins = 0;
var timer;
var start = 0;
var stop = 0;

function add() {
  secs++;
  if (secs == 60) {
    mins++;
    secs = 0;
  }
  if (mins == 6) {
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
  }

  display();
}

function startc() {
  if (start == 0) {
    timer = setInterval(add, 1000);
    start = 1;
  }
}

function stopc() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  start = 0;
  stop = 1;
}

function clearc() {
  secs = 0;
  mins = 0;
  clearInterval(timer);
  display();
  if (stop != 1) {
    start = 0;
    startc();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. We can't tell when your functions are called or by what. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display milliseconds passed between clicking different buttons, then I think you don't need such a complicated code. (I used jQuery.)

```js
let start = 0
let stop = 0
let isRunning = false

$('#start').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!isRunning) {
    start = Date.now()
    isRunning = true
  }
})

$('#stop').on('click', function(e) {
  if (isRunning) {
    stop = Date.now()
    display(start, stop)
    isRunning = false
  }
})

const display = (start, stop) => {
  $("#displayms").text(stop - start + ' ms')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start" class="btn">START</button><br />
<button id="stop" class="btn">STOP</button>
<hr />
<div>MILLISECONDS PASSED: <span id="displayms">0 ms</span></div>
```